# If Else for when a button is pressed javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thank You. I had previously done it like many of you have suggested but the issue I had/have is that my project is a text based game changing according to my choices(Option 1 or Option 2), I attempted to use If statements so that the code would run from one option to the next, with If statements within each other until the end, each option contained within what option you pressed to trigger it. Perhaps that is not the way to got about it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dungeonStyle.css">
</head>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress() {
        document.getElementById("gameText").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("optionOne").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("optionTwo").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("bTEXT").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("bTEXT2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    window.onload = codeAddress;
    </script>
  </head>    

<body>

<div id="startup">
<div class="header">
<h1>DUNGEON DUELER</h1>
</div>

<p id="subtitle">The Interactive Novel</p>
<p id="gameDescription">Your choices forge  your destiny</p>


<button  id = "startButton" onclick="startGame()">Click to begin!
</button>

<p id="gameText">
You're in search of gold and glory. Conquer this dungeon and it shall be yours!
</p>    

<button id = "optionOne" onclick="One()">Option One</button>
<button id = "optionTwo" onclick="Two()">Option Two</button>

<p2 id = "bTEXT">Begin </p2>
<p3 id = "bTEXT2">stuff</p3>

<Script>
function startGame() {
document.getElementById("startButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("subtitle").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("gameDescription").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("gameText").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("optionOne").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("optionTwo").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("bTEXT").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("bTEXT2").style.visibility = "visible";

}   
</Script>
```

the issue

```
if (function one.onclick){
    var str = document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML; 
var txt = str.replace("You're in search of gold and glory. Conquer this dungeon and it shall be yours!","blah blah blah");
document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css is on separate file .

I'll attempt to explain myself the best I can. I'm making a text based game with two button that determine the results. I am trying so that If option one is pressed run the code (change the text thats displayed and hp system) else do other code/option.

My first upload, apologies for any errors. Newbie.

Comment: `if (function one.onclick)` ... Er, what?

Comment: change <Script> to <script>

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) You appear to have a syntax error. @ShyA While it's preferable to use `<script>`, [the case doesn't actually matter.](https://jsfiddle.net/9xmh59rq/)

Comment: @RickyD check out [here jsbin](https://jsbin.com/niyorijoho/edit?html,output) this is the behavior that you want ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to define the Event handlers for the onclick events `One` and `Two`. 
   In the functions `One` and `Two` you can define the logic which needs to be implemented. The event handler can be either a [function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) or a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). In your case it is a function Declaration. Also, you can pass the `MouseEvent` Object in the parameters which contains the information of the event encapsulated in the object, which can provide helpful information about the event.
2. Change the `Script` to `script`

```js
function One(){
    var str = document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML; 
  var txt = str.replace("You're in search of gold and glory. Conquer this dungeon and it shall be yours!","blah blah blah");
  document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML = txt;

}


function Two(){
    // The other logic

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dungeonStyle.css">
</head>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress() {
        document.getElementById("gameText").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("optionOne").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("optionTwo").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("bTEXT").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("bTEXT2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    window.onload = codeAddress;
    </script>
  </head>    

<body>

<div id="startup">
<div class="header">
<h1>DUNGEON DUELER</h1>
</div>

<p id="subtitle">The Interactive Novel</p>
<p id="gameDescription">Your choices forge  your destiny</p>


<button  id = "startButton" onclick="startGame()">Click to begin!
</button>

<p id="gameText">
You're in search of gold and glory. Conquer this dungeon and it shall be yours!
</p>    

<button id = "optionOne" onclick="One()">Option One</button>
<button id = "optionTwo" onclick="Two()">Option Two</button>

<p2 id = "bTEXT">Begin </p2>
<p3 id = "bTEXT2">stuff</p3>

<script>
function startGame() {
document.getElementById("startButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("subtitle").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("gameDescription").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("gameText").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("optionOne").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("optionTwo").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("bTEXT").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("bTEXT2").style.visibility = "visible";

}   
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You. I had previously done it like so but the issue I had/have is that my project is a text based game changing according to my choices(Option 1 or Option 2), I attempted to use If statements so that the code would run from one option to the next, with If statements within each other until the end. Perhaps that is not the way to got about it.

Comment: I am not exactly clear as to what you are asking, If you could add more information to the question then i might be able to help.

Comment: I understand the confusion. I am trying to make a text based game that evolves on your decisions. much like telltale games or something of the sort. To do so I have two buttons. When a button is pressed it'll change the text in the text box and the button option descriptions. The IF statement is so that each choice leads into the next. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (function one.onclick){
```

should be

```
function One(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things here. First, i didn't saw the opening script tag in your code (and the first script tag, change `Script` to `script` :

```
<script>
if (function one.onclick){
    var str = document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML; 
    var txt = str.replace("You're in search of gold and glory. Conquer this 
    dungeon and it shall be yours!","blah blah blah");
    document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Second, and most important, the IF condition:

```
<script>
function one() {
    var str = document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML; 
    var txt = str.replace("You're in search of gold and glory. Conquer this 
    dungeon and it shall be yours!","blah blah blah");
    document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Try to always use the `console.log()`, it is your friend always, hehe!